# How to categorize data using an ifstatement in a datagridview C#

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, datagridview

I have created a program which takes a persons details. These details include 5 ski times. The person then has to take a test on ski safety. I have created various data grid views at the end of the quiz - showing the test scores in ascending order and the average ski times of each person.

I am trying now to create  a data grid view which will categoize each player as a "Beginner" "Intermediate" or "Advanced" This will be based on the average ski times and the test score results. 
Can any one help me out as to how I could populate the cell of the Level heading to show one of these 3 categories automatically using the data already collected.

The code attached shows a datagridview showing the persons name, their ID, the test score and the average time -I would love to show another column with the level in. time is the average time of the ski times and detailsArray2[8] is the location of the score.

All help appreciated.

```
public frmReactionTimes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();



        try
        {
            if (File.Exists("competitorDetailsFile.txt")) //if this file 
exists
            {
                string[] detailsArray = 
File.ReadLines("competitorDetailsFile.txt").ToArray(); //write data to 
array
                double time = 0;
                double time1 = 0;



                for (int number = 0; number < detailsArray.Length; 
number++)
                {
                    string[] detailsArray2 = 
detailsArray[number].Split('~'); //split on tilda

                    time1 = Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[3]) + 
Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[4]) + Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[5]) + 
Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[6]) + Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[7]);
                    time = time1 / 5;

                    //time is equaal to the total of the climb times and 
reaction times
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(detailsArray2[0], 
Convert.ToDouble(detailsArray2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(detailsArray2[8]), 
time);


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you have pasted is incomplete which will make it quite difficult for anyone to understand it well enough to be able to help.  Please edit your question to include the rest of your code -- at a minimum you should be showing complete blocks (between opening/closing curly braces `{}`).

Comment: Thanks, I have edited to show more code.